# How can I resolve all subdomains to an A record?

Tags: linux, domain-name-system

I have a `*.domain.com` that I want to resolve into a specific IP.

This `*.domain.com` has public records, so I want a new local one that overwrites them.

I've tried Bind in a Docker container, but it's too complex (I don't want to learn how to configure it now), and I need a quick solution. Can I do it using the `/etc/resolv.conf`?

Comment: Look at `unbound` and `dnsmasq` they should be enough for a quick local recursive resolver bypassing a specific resolution. Please don't use `domain.com` when you obfuscate, this name exists and is obviously not yours. The placeholder designed for those needs is `example.com`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use dnsmask and try this option in dnsmasq.conf
address=/example.com/127.0.0.1

Thx to
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49896355/21237706